# error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'char*'

Tags: c++, char

I have a small problem. I keep getting this error: **error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'char*'** for this part of the code (`list<lst>* listSearch(list<lst> *LST, char* wrd, KEY key)`).

What am I doing wrong here?

```
enum KEY {code, disease} key;

struct lst
{
    char *_code;
    char *_disease;
    lst* next;
};


bool isPartOf(char* word, char* sentence)
{
    unsigned int i=0;
    unsigned int j=0;

    for(i;i < strlen(sentence); i++)
    {
        if(sentence[i] == word[j])
        {
            j++;
        }
    }

    if(strlen(word) == j)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

list<lst>* listSearch(list<lst> *LST,char* wrd,KEY key)
{
    list<lst> resultList;
    list<lst>* result;

    switch(key)
    {
    case code:
        for(list<lst>::iterator i = LST->begin(); i != LST->end(); i++)
        {
            if(isPartOf(wrd, *i._code))
            {
                resultList.push_back(*i);
            }
        }
        break;

    case disease:
        for(list<lst>::iterator i = LST->begin(); i != LST->end(); i++)
        {
            if(isPartOf(wrd, *i->_disease))
                resultList.push_back(*i);
        }
        break;
    }

    result = &resultList;

    return result;
}
```

Comment: How are you calling the last function?

Comment: You're passing a `char` in place of a `char*` on the line the compiler tells you (which you haven't even so much as mentioned to us). Why would it work?

Comment: Please switch to `std::string` to avoid this kind of issues.

Comment: BTW, identifiers (variable names) with leading underscores are usually reserved for compilers and my cause collisions with your code.  So, if you must use underscores, place them at the end.

Comment: Returning a pointer to a local variable is not a good idea; the variable is destroyed when the function exits, so you are inviting disaster.  You're embedding your `lst` type in a `list<lst>`, so you don't need the `next` element in `lst`, do you?  It is curious that one of your calls to `isPartOf()` using `*i->_disease` and the other uses `*i._code` when the types appear to be symmetric.  Inconsistency is bad.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a compiler bug. At least the compiler shall issue another error message.

The problem is related to operator priorities. This statement

```
if(isPartOf(wrd, *i._code))
```

must be written like

```
if(isPartOf(wrd, ( *i )._code))
```

It seems that the compiler issued the error for this statement

```
if(isPartOf(wrd, *i->_disease))
```

It must be written like

```
if(isPartOf(wrd, i->_disease))
```

because expression `*i->_disease` has type char but you have to pass to the function an object of type `char *`

And using this function can result in undefined behaviour because it returns pointer to a local object.

```
list<lst>* listSearch(list<lst> *LST,char* wrd,KEY key)
{
    list<lst> resultList;
    list<lst>* result;

    //...

    result = &resultList;

    return result;
}
```

Take into account that function `isPartOf` is logically wrong. For example when `word` is equal "ab" and `sentence` is equal to "a1111b" the function will return true. I do not think you mean this logic.

Comment: "must be written like"? Isn't using `i->_code` considered more clear?

Comment: @Tim Seguine I showed the correct syntax of using operator *.

Comment: I know. I was suggesting to (in addition to what you wrote) recommend a clearer more idiomatic syntax for writing the same thing.